# Saving dictionary data to django model problem, error message = AttributeError("'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'")

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a problem, saving a dictionary data to django model.

Did I need to input sqlite3 query somewhere?

Please teach me how can I solution this problem.

received dictionary data

> {"id":20,"title":"random data","temp":43.70915909663141,"humidity":10.40750545208753,"created_date":"2021-12-15T16:25:12.946427","author":1}

Error message

> {"id":20,"title":"random
> data","temp":43.70915909663141,"humidity":10.40750545208753,"created_date":"2021-12-15T16:25:12.946427","author":1}
> Unexpected e=AttributeError("'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'"),
> type(e)=<class 'AttributeError'>

modles.py

```
class Data(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    temp = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    humidity = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = '__all__'
```

snd_clienet.py

```
     data = Data(
                    id = 20,
                    author = User.objects.get(username='labovming'),
                    title = 'random data',
                    temp = random.random()*300,
                    humidity = random.random()*12,
                    created_date = timezone.now()
                )

                serializer = DataSerializer(data)
                msg = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
```

rcv_server.py

```
while msg:  
    stream = io.BytesIO(msg)
    data = JSONParser().parse(stream)
    serializer = DataSerializer(data=data) # create new instance
    serializer = DataSerializer(data, data=data) # update 'data'
    # serializer = CommentSerializer(comment, data={'content': u'foo bar'}, partial=True)  # Update `comment` with partial data
    serializer.is_valid()  **<<< Validation fail ** 
    serializer.errors      
    serializer.validated_data  **<<< Empty ** 

    try: 
        serializer.save()  **<<< Error occur here ** 
        print(f'data added : {serializer}')
        if self.DBman.messageHandler(Name, msg.decode()) == -1: 
            self.request.close() 
            break 
        msg = self.request.recv(1024) 

    except Exception as e: 
        print(f"Unexpected {e=}, {type(e)=}") 
        break
```

Comment: I solve this problem. 
Comment out update data line


serializer = DataSerializer(data=data) # create new instance
# serializer = DataSerializer(data, data=data) # update 'data'


In order to be continuously added to the database, the id must be changed every time.


Another issue is that same error occurs using update data line.
Is there any condition for updating django model?